# Why was this question about early check-in closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The question [What's the point of checking in several days before a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171357/1810) was closed as opinion-based. Why? The existing answers show there exist objective reasons, e.g. seat selection or increasing the likelihood to board the flight in case of overbooking. Most close votes were cast after the first objective answer was posted.

---

From the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/opinion): opinion =
a thought or belief about something or someone.

From https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions:

> Opinion-based: discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well.
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: As usual, someone voted to close, some more agreed and also voted to close, so now the question is closed. As you well know.  Edit: Was closed.

Comment: @Willeke not my fault if the people who cast the close votes don't explain their votes in the comment section.

Comment: We explicitly do not ask people to explain votes in the comment section, and we keep votes anonymous, because that has been shown to provide the best quality control across SE. There are various posts on meta.se you can look at for more info.

Comment: @RoryAlsop indeed  they don't have to.  This is why I have to resort to meta to understand what's going on. Eg  your answer is helpful for me to understand even though I don't agree.

Answer (score 2):

As @Willeke commented, various folks reckoned it was opinion-based and voted to close it, including me. As you can see from the varied answers this has been shown to be correct - each answer has a different opinion, and I can think of a few more, so there is no objective answer that is fully correct here.

Please re-read the help pages and read the full description for each close reason, as they have all the information you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132642/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-why-was-this-question-about-early-check-in-cl).